# Using a known WorkItem ID, how does one get the workflow version of the item (component) in TOM.NET?

Tags: workflow, tom.net

Given a WorkItem ID (e.g. "tcm:x-y-131200"), what is the proper way to get the workflow version of the item (component) in TOM.NET framework?

The following does not seem to return the workflow version. The compUri (Line 3) returns the non-workflow version number, and consequently the component (Line 4) is not the workflow version of the item.

```
TcmUri workItemUri = new TcmUri(workItemId);
WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(workItemUri, new Session());
TcmUri compUri = workItem.Subject.Id;
Component component = (Component)session.GetObject(compUri);
```

It was previously done successfully in a Process Definition VBScript using the following:

```
Dim oComp
Set oComp = CurrentWorkItem.GetItem(1)
Dim oCompEdit
Set oCompEdit = TDSE.GetObject(oComp.ID, 2)
```

Comment: BTW, TOM.NET is not a supported API for workflow activities. Either use COM or CoreService (if release >= 2011)

Comment: Also it usually isn't a good idea to create a new Session object yourself. This is most of the time an indication that you are trying to use the TOM.NET API in a location where it is not supposed to be used. If you are in Template code you could for instance get the Session through `engine.GetSession()` and in the event system through `subject.Session`.

Comment: I meant... use COM for Tridion 2009 or earlier and use CoreService for Tridion 2011 or later.

Comment: Thank you, @NunoLinhares and @BartKoopman. The farthest I get with `CoreServiceClient` is in getting the `WorkItemData.Subject` (which is of `LinkToVersionedItemData` type) value. It looks like its `IdRef` and `Title` property is still showing the non-workflow version values.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to read the item in this case, you can just use the `Subject` property:

```csharp
TcmUri workItemUri = new TcmUri(workItemId);
WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(workItemUri, new Session());
Component component = (Component) workItem.Subject;
```

The Component will be read just in time (JIT) as soon as you access some of its properties.

Comment: I tested getting the Subject property directly, unfortunately it is returning the non-workflow version of the component.

Comment: @Arif You should be the performer of the current activity